# Climatempo para incluir no site

Tags: xml, script

Alguém saberia me informa onde poderia encontra um xml ou algum script para inserir a a previsão do climatempo da praia *tabua de marés* em meu site?

Estou precisando algo assim desse site:

http://www.climatempo.com.br/tabua-de-mares/

Poderiam me da um help?

Comment: Você quer incluir os dados do climaetempo, tabua de mares me parece o nome da praia apenas. Você quer pegar aqueles dados da previsão?

Comment: Olá @GuilhermeNascimento cara eu quero pegar apenas os dados da Tabua de Maré!

Comment: Olá Luciano, sim é por isto que editei a pergunta, para ficar mais clara, mas infelizmente não encontrei API alguma para isto. Só pode ser em javascript ou você usa PHP, RubyOnRails ou outra linguagem de servidor?

Comment: O climatempo não tem RSS disso? Se tiver, você pode ler o RSS. Acho que o site do INPE tem alguns serviços em XML. Uma vez obtendo o XML, fica fácil extrair a informação (usando Scrapy, por exemplo). Se você não encontrar em lugar nenhum, dá para extrair do HTML, embora exista o risco do site mudar e sua app falhar quando isso acontecer.

Comment: https://github.com/raphaelVidinha/tabuaDeMare

Comment: https://github.com/LuisAraujo/API-Tabua-Mare

Answer (score 4):

O site do CPTEC tem alguns serviços em xml.
http://servicos.cptec.inpe.br/XML/

Comment: Fiz um Aplicativo usando a API -  XML desse site aqui (http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/) ele tem as informalçõe sem Json tbem se preferir

Comment: Muito bom, fiz com a API desse site http://openweathermap.org/api
Fiz em Json e em um em  XML nesse tem muitas outras informações.
Esse site tem além do tempo, índice UV, Poluição do Ar, dados de estações meteorológicas ... muito bom
Assim como o Matheus falou abaixo

Answer (score 2):

Eu utilizo um código em PHP que se conecta a API do http://openweathermap.org/,
e passo como parâmetros a cidade no meu caso Araci-Bahia, a medida e a linguagem, ele retorna um JSON após isso é só você tratar o JSON.

No meu caso eu chamo esse PHP via Ajax, aí faço todo tratamento, iteração, etc.

```
function get_weather(){
 try{
    $obj = file_get_contents("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=araci,brasil&lang=pt&units=metric");
    $item = json_decode($obj);
    //no meu caso dou a saída para o AJAX onde trato
    return round($item->main->temp);
 }catch(Exception $ex){
       //trata o erro
 }
}
```

Comment: Não achei a parte de tábua de marés nesse OpenWeatherMap, sabe me informar se tem?